# Is it possible to create an eternal ring of storm encircling a large portion of the earth?

Tags: science-fiction, weather

I'm trying to investigate the theory behind this phenomena. I have found answers to creating eternal storms but nothing specific to my world building. I'm looking at a future earth where any known inhabitants is encircled by a perpetual storm in a misshapen ring form.

Whether the cause is the side effects of weaponry, natural causes, or man-made devices, is an acceptable answer. Or is it possible to create an anticyclonic scenario where a man-made device creates the right conditions for a storm as described?

If anyone could even provide the tools or references to come up with a half accurate scenario it would be appreciated.

Comment: "any known inhabitants is encircled by a perpetual storm". Do you mean a personal storm? Kind of 7 billions storms if it was today?

Comment: No, a singular storm surrounding the society of inhabitants, not every person having their own personal storm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storms, in one sense, are a method of distributing heat from land and sea to the air. More heat leads to more intense and more frequent storms. More heat in one area leads to more intense and more frequent storms in that area.

In this case, the ring or area must closely match one of the existing four prevailing wind zones (westerlies or trade winds, northern or southern):

[image]

Storms generally grow over water and degrade over land, so a ring of storms won't work well in the Northern Hemisphere...but take a look at the [constant ring of storms](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i4mBYwBNULk) around Antarctica

**There are two problems with a man-made misshapen ring of storms**. The first is that humans have no terrestrial technology that can focus that much energy into one area. The only powerful source we have is the sun. Perhaps humans can build space-based mirrors to focus more heat into specific areas of ocean.

However, the second (and bigger problem) is that more heat means a *hotter Earth*, warmer oceans, and a very different climate.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. The information has been very helpful. Weather is a delicate lady. Deep thinking time for me.

Answer (score 2):

Since your world is a future Earth that makes one possible solution possible. Although this could only happen a very, very long way in the the future. In fact, the very far future.

Allow for enough continental drift to move the continents out of the way to permit a planet-girdling free path. This is essentially similar to the Roaring Forties circling Antarctica. Continents break up and literally put the brakes wind circulation patterns. Once the continents are out of the way, the wind circulation pattern simply goes on unchecked. This is effectively a permanent ring of storms.

This future Earth could have a hotter global climate. This would greatly assist the existence of a ring of storms. A hotter Earth will have more energy in its weather systems. This means inevitably more powerful storms and much more extreme weather generally. For example, this would be especially true if the continent-free path was located as this Earth's equator.

There is no weapon or super-weapon our species is likely to develop that is capable of creating the ring of storms. Although this might become possible in the far future. However, this answer has stuck to possible natural systems like a hotter Earth combined the continental drift to result in a planet ringed with permanent storms (where on the planet is left as an exercise for the OP)

This answer notes and acknowledges its similarities to the good answer already posted by @user53733. We were drawing on similar ideas.